# Accessing POD's from cypress on windows throws an error

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, cypress

**we are trying to access a log file from a POD using the following script  in cypress Test and we are getting and error as below and was wondering how can we execute this from windows**

```
Information about the failure:

Code: 127

Stderr:

/c/Program: Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: No such file or directory
```

**When we use the following method**

```html
function getFile(podList, fileDir, file) {
  const allEnvironment = Cypress.env('ALL_ALL_ENVIRONMENT');
  const nextStep = Cypress.spec.name;

  podList.forEach((pod) => {
    cy.exec(`kubectl exec ${pod} -- bash -c 'cat ${fileDir}${file}'`, { failOnNonZeroExit: false })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.code === 1) {
          console.error(`No file ${fileDir}${file} found on POD ${pod}`);
          throw new Error(`No file ${fileDir}${file} found on POD ${pod}`);
        } else if (result.code === 0) {
          const fileData = Cypress.env('ExpectedResult') + result.stdout;
          Cypress.env('ExpectedResult', fileData);

          cy.wrap(fileData).as('fileData');

          cy.log(`${fileDir}${file} has been retrieved successfully from POD ${pod}`);
        } else {
          console.error(`Exit ${result.code} from pod ${pod}`);
          console.error(`Error getting data from POD ${pod}, error is: ${result.stderr}`);
          throw new Error(`Error getting data from POD ${pod}, error is: ${result.stderr}`);
        }
      });
  });

  cy.log('File has been retrieved successfully.');
}
```

Comment: It's because of this `-- bash`. Can you provide the name of the image that the pod is using?

Comment: `\adm-s4-pxxx1-0` @Hackerman

Comment: Maybe for the error message I can asume that it is a windows machine; if that is the use case, then you are not going to be able to run bash on that; unless you install gitbash as an extra step on your Dockerfile

Comment: isnt thr any way we can execute this via JS or  If there is any other way we could interact with kubernetes cluster via another lib